# Cannot connect MySQL server to visual studio; Connection Error 40

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio

I'm trying to connect a local MySQL 8 server to Visual Studio 2019. As far as I can tell, I've installed all of the right packages for both including the .net connector for MySQL. I can access and manipulate the database through the command line just fine, and the server itself is running. But when I try to access it from Visual studio or SMSS, it waits for about 10 seconds or so and throws error 40, claiming it cannot find or connect to my server. I have allowed firewall access, enabled TCP/IP, named pipelines and shared memory per instructions of other answers and even reinstalled the entire server. I seriously cannot get this to work and really need some help. The error is below.

`A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)`

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to provide the entire error message, not just the error number? It's on the screen right in front of you, so there's no reason you shouldn't be able to provide it to us as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMSS only connects to SQL Server, not MySQL. The error message also specifically says it's attempting to open an SQL Server connection, not MySQL. Either use the [MySQL data provider through Server Explorer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-connection-server-explorer.html#visual-studio-connection-server-explorer-basic) or use the [MySQL Connection Manager](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-connection-manager.html#visual-studio-connection-manager-basic)

Comment: As it would turn out, I have a bad case of monkey brain and your last link helped me find what I was looking for. After some reading there, I was finally able to get it working. Thanks a ton, sorry for the stupid question.